# Program to convert a laptop into a USB storage

Tags: software-rec, usb-storage

I usually have problems doing networks between two computers I have. My intention is to pass files from one to the other. I was wondering if there is any simple and easy program to install that gives me the option to connect the two computers through a USB wire and to access from one computer to the other like if one of the two computers were a simple USB mass storage.

Answer (score 3):

Cool idea. I would think it'd be easier to connect them via a ethernet cable and setup file sharing on the file you want to share (assuming you're using two OSs that support CIFS shares). That's easy in windows and OS X.

I'll explain more if that'd be helpful, but I won't go into more detail yet since it doesn't directly answer your Q.

Answer (score 2):

As Blackbeagle noted in his comment, you *could* use a [special USB cable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easy_Transfer_Cable):

> The Easy Transfer Cable is a USB 2.0
> device which is used to connect two
> computers together. The connectors are
> both USB-A male connectors to connect
> to each PC, but the cable also has a
> small box in the middle which contains
> the needed electronics and chipset to
> allow the two connected computers to
> communicate with each other, and keeps
> the two computers connected
> electronically continuous (a direct
> USB-A to USB-A cable between each
> computer should not be used due to a
> short circuit risk).

**However.** If you were able to post this question to superuser, chances are you would be better served just using Ethernet.

Note that, with Ethernet, if both Windows PCs use DHCP, plugging them together should "just work", and all you have to do to reference files on the other PC is open a folder on it like: `\\other-pc\c$\path-to-my-files`. You shouldn't even need to set up a shared drive, since you probably will have all user credentials handy anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at other solutions that are designed for Syncing files between computers? for example [DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/) is a great tool for keeping a folder of docs synced over the internet between computers.

Comment: Yes, dropbox is fantastic, but not perfect because the free version has a limit of storage

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible in software due to the way USB works. What exactly are the problems you're having with networking?

Comment: Take a look to this other question (it´s related with this one) http://serverfault.com/questions/226798/how-much-time-its-neccesary-to-make-a-network-between-two-computers

Comment: -1 Lookup USB Transfer cable in Google.  Plug the special USB cable into both computers, you might have to run software, usually not, and the two computers should be visible to each other in Explorer.  Drag and drop files between the two computers.

Comment: Why the downvote? I realize of course that there's a thing like USB transfer cables, but those come at some ~30 bucks mostly, and it's easier to follow one or two easy networking tricks to get the job done for free.

Comment: if you know it is possible(with a usb transfer cable) then you shouldn't suggest or say that it isn't. hardware does cost. i suppose a usb transfer cable is a bit lame though what with ethernet.. it's like sticking a sign up saying "I can't set it up with ethernet and windows file sharing!"

Comment: I agree, I might have mentioned that it is *possible*, but still: I don't think an answer only has to answer the question that has been asked, but also to point to better ways of doing what the OP wants to do. And ethernet is both cheaper and faster than USB transfers and it isn't exactly rocket science, is it?

Comment: @Tobias It can be useful to mention another way, but that doesn't include saying that it isn't possible with USB when not only it is, but you know it is. (even if you don't think it's a good way to go about it)

Comment: Yep, yep, might have been a bit more clear on that.

Comment: @Blackbeagle: About your suggestion to use a USB transfer cable - Yes, that would work; note however that the question asks how to access the computer "like [...] an simple usb mass storage." Using a USB transfer cable does not achieve this, as it cannot present a mass storage interface (at least no cable I know does this).

Comment: @sleske  the questioner didn't need it to pop up as a separate drive/usb mass storage device popup thing. he just wanted to transfer files, it looks like he just threw the usb mass storage device in there as an idea but not necessary.. he said what his intention is and didn't rule anything out or clearly restrict things to that only, and there's no obvious reason why he would.

Comment: @barlop: Fair enough. Then Ethernet is probably the best option :-).

Comment: @sleske  there are other options.. somebody once mentioned a program to me called "network magic" but it seems it's not free, but it has a free trial.  Alternatively you can have a sleepless night or week setting up file sharing, but once it's set up, it's seamless and really good. But actually network magic looks very cheap, basic version is $23. USB transfer cable isn't a bad idea.I suppose make sure it's USB2 not USB1,or it'd be too slow.but usb2(480mbps) is faster than 100mbps form of ethernet that people tend to have. they're all good options.dunno if weak link isn't hdd speed prob isnt!